# Weird setting when linking to Postgresql using Windows authentication or SQL authentication

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I wanted to read AWS Postgresql from within SQL Server, so

I created a system ODBC connection to Postgresql on the SQL Server machine, tested it, fine.

I then created a Linked Server to connect to postgresql.
In the Security tab (For a login not defined in the list above, connections will), I selected "Be made using the login's current security context".

When using this linked server while connected to SQL Server through windows authentication, it works fine.

If I connect to SQL Server using a SQL Server authenticated account, trying to access postgresql data through that same Linked Server fails authentication.

I fixed that by switching my security setting to "Be made using this security context" and giving the POSTGRESQL login/password (same that I gave at the ODBC level).

Question:

Without repeating the postgresql details at the Linked Server stage, why is it working with Window sauthentication account and not for SQL Server authenticated accounts?

Neither are relevant to Postgresql?...

I made it work but still confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to guess a bit to help you, but I hope to give you enough context to understand what is happening so you can debug further.

When you connect to SQL Server using integrated authentication, the domain controller gives out a token to talk to SQL and this is used to authenticate your connection from your client to SQL Server's process.  Underneath the covers, Windows can use either NTLM or Kerberos to do this handshake.  You can read more about this here in this blog post:
[NTLM vs. Kerberos Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections/).  This protocol choice matters when trying to use linked servers since it has to then authenticate to something else over the network.

At this point, it matters what credentials are used to run SQL Server (usually as a service in the services window to see).  If you are running SQL as Local System or Network Service or something else defined by windows (instead of as a specific user on the network), it may or may not have permissions to talk out to your target remote server (whether it be postgres or something else).  When you use Kerberos and enable delegation (which the domain admin needs to do), you can have the original integrated auth credentials "flow" over the linked server link to the next connection.  NTLM does not do this.  Therefore, the usual scenario is to create a map in the local SQL Server of what credentials to use when talking out to a remote linked server.

If you are talking to an ODBC driver, then you are likely using the msdasql (OLEDB to ODBC bridge) provider and then also having to go through its authentication stack.  It has been too long for my memory as to whether it even supports integrated auth at all, much less delegation in Kerberos.  However, you may be able to debug this problem further if you:

- consider which account is running SQL
- consider which mechanism is used to do integrated auth to sql and whether that would work with delegation
- determine which credentials are used to make the outbound connection to your ODBC target.  You should be able to debug much of this through the profiler mechanism as there is a distributed query/linked server set of events IIRC.

I can't speak to your postgres provider specifically, but this should give you some more tools to debug.  Hope that helps you get one step further.

Comment: Thanks, this is VERY useful